# Can MySQL transactions be used with event scheduler?

Tags: mysql, transactions

Can I use MySQL transactions on an InnoDB table inside MySQL event? Are there any restrictions on the event scheduler?

Comment: (OT: you don't need to sign your posts (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), your user card does that already. And you don't need salutations at the top either, nor do you need `<br/>`s - just hit enter twice instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are limits on InnoDB Tables

Warning

Do not convert MySQL system tables in the mysql database from MyISAM to InnoDB tables! This is an unsupported operation. If you do this, MySQL does not restart until you restore the old system tables from a backup or re-generate them with the mysql_install_db script.

Warning

It is not a good idea to configure InnoDB to use data files or log files on NFS volumes. Otherwise, the files might be locked by other processes and become unavailable for use by MySQL.

****Go to follwoing link

[restrictions on the event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/ja/events-limitations-restrictions.html)

Hope its help you!!!